# how to set a default view in angular calender (e.g.for a week view)

Tags: angular

I am trying gave a default week view to my angular calender currently it is showing month by default
https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink

can you anyone suggest how can we do this,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default view to week by changing the view.

```
view: CalendarView = CalendarView.Month;
```

to

```
view: CalendarView = CalendarView.Week;
```

Please check the [demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lmkiee?file=demo%2Fcomponent.ts) and https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-calendar?activeTab=versions

To change the default views

```
view: CalendarView = CalendarView.Week; // week
view: CalendarView = CalendarView.Month; // month
view: CalendarView = CalendarView.Day; // day
```